# How to add custom Bullets in amCharts Area Chart?

Tags: javascript, css, data-visualization, amcharts

Is there any way to add custom Bullets in amcharts Area Chart similar to below (Bottom-right of the chart)?

[image]

Is it feasible at all?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: JSFiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/3e9y84xy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this:

1) add another graph to your chart, set stackable to false, lineAlpha to 0 and visibleInLegend to false. This way this graph won't affect other graphs and will be invisible.

2) in your data, at the series (2010) add value3 (or some other field name) with value 66

3) in the same data item add path to the image of your custom bullet, like:

"bullet": "http://www.amcharts.com//lib/3/images/3.gif"

4) set customBulletField: "bullet" for your invisible graph.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding custom class to bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600150/adding-a-custom-class-to-bullets-in-amcharts)