# Adding a custom class to bullets in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add a class name to a custom bullet, so I can position it with CSS. I'm also trying to add a value to that custom bullet. I don't think I have it set right in the gauge js:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("maint-good", {
    "type": "serial",
    "rotate": true,
    "theme": "light",
    "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
    "autoMargins": false,
    "marginTop": 80,
    "marginLeft": 80,
    "marginBottom": 30,
    "marginRight": 50,
    "addClassNames": true,
    "dataProvider": [{
        "marginTop": 80,
        "category": "",
        "excelent": 20,
        "good": 20,
        "average": 20,
        "poor": 20,
        "bad": 20,
        "limit": 15,
        "full": 15,
        "bullet": 15,
        "icon": "assets/img/icons/maint_good.svg",
        "ok": "assets/img/icons/ok.svg"

    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "maximum": 20,
        "stackType": "regular",
        "gridAlpha": 0

    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "columnWidth": 0.6,
        "lineColor": "#2F2F2F",
        "lineThickness": 22,
        "noStepRisers": true,
        "stackable": false,
        "type": "step",
        "valueField": "limit",
        "bulletSize": 95,
        "customBulletField": "icon"
    }, {
        "valueField": "full",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "type": "column",
        "lineAlpha": 0,
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "fillColors": ["#2F2F2F", "#2F2F2F", "#2F2F2F"],
        "gradientOrientation": "horizontal"
    }, {
        "clustered": false,
        "columnWidth": 0.3,
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "lineColor": "#8dc53e",
        "stackable": false,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "bullet",
        "customBulletField": "ok",
        "bulletSize": 95,

    }],
    "columnWidth": 1,
    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "display": "none"
    }

});
```

The two bullets I'm trying to add a class to are "icon" and "ok". I know there is documentation in amCharts for this, but it does not give any examples. Could someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use graph's property [`classNameField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#classNameField) to specify which field in data holds a custom class name to be applied for the specific data point.

I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
  // ... other graph settings
  "customBulletField": "icon",
  "classNameField": "iconClass"
}, ...
```

In data:

```
"dataProvider": [{
  // ...
  "icon": "assets/img/icons/maint_good.svg",
  "iconClass": "icon",
  // ...
}]
```

Now, the chart will apply both the hardcoded class name "amcharts-graph-bullet" and custom class name, such as "icon":

[image]

Now you can target this specific bullet using CSS:

```
.amcharts-graph-bullet.icon image {
  /* your css here */
}
```

Please note, that in order for the above to work, the [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames) setting needs to be enabled. You already have that set in your code, just though it's worth mentioning for anyone else, looking for similar solution.

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: how to add custom class to the legends? just adding class to graphs does not work for me.